# Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to use the SOAP webservice described by the below WSDL:
http://qaws.ssichilexpress.cl/TarificarCourier?wsdl

I tried:

```
public function __construct($config) {
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, [
        'trace' => true,
        'exceptions' => true
    ]);
}

public function tarifar($data) {
    try {
        $this->client->TarificarCourier([
            'reqValorizarCourier' => $data
        ]);
    } catch(SoapFault $fault) {
        die($fault->getCode() . ': ' . $fault->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But i get a SoapFault with message "Could not connect to host".
Any ideas ?

**EDIT 1:**

Also i tried:

```
public function __construct($config) {
   $this->config = $config;
   $this->wsdl = null;
   $this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, [
      'trace' => true,
      'exceptions' => true,
      'location' => 'http://qaws.ssichilexpress.cl/',
      'uri' => 'TarificarCourier'
   ]);
}

public function tarifar($data) {
   try {
      $this->client->__soapCall('TarificarCourier', [
         'reqValorizarCourier' => $data
      ]);
   } catch(SoapFault $fault) {
      die('SFinReq: ' . $fault->getCode() . ': ' . $fault->getMessage());
   }
}
```

But, i get a SoapFault with "Not Found" message.

Comment: Just checked it out in Chroms Boomerang app. Didn't get any response back. But saw that there are a transaction header in the request, with some parameters, that might have to be defined to connect. Maybe that's the probleme